# Get file from the linux_volshell from volatility

Tags: linux, forensics, volatility

I am analyzing a mem and trying to recover a file that an attacker used to exploit drupalgeddon2 vulnerability. I discover that the process with `pid 11046` executes the request with the file `h38x.php` (the one the attacker submitted).

I need to somehow extract the file or its hash. Is there any way to do that with volatility?